# cbm prg studio for the Amstrad

Tags: assembly, basic, software-development, cpc464, software-development-kit

CBM prg studio is brilliant.

I have searched Google for a version (or something similar) for the Amstrad CPC 464, to no avail.

Does anyone know of one?

Answer (score 4):

The nearest I can think of — though still very far from CBM prg Studio's integration — is [CPCtelera](http://lronaldo.github.io/cpctelera/). It's mostly for C development, and the BASIC and debugging components that make prg Studio so clever aren't there.

I didn't find any shining stars in the [Programming:Cross Development - CPCWiki](http://www.cpcwiki.eu/index.php/Programming:Cross_Development) category. I've mostly made do with a mix of z88dk's *appmake* and iDsK for cross development.